# How to use AlarmManager with the data that is stored in SQLite Database?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, notifications, alarmmanager

I am making an alarm application where the user selects date and time. The data is stored in an SQL database. What i want to do is to call a notification once that time is reached. I tried doing this by simply using the time slected by the user, but the alarm still exists even if I delete the alarm or edit the time. That is why I need to use the data from the database, so if the alarm is deleted, the notification would not go through. I have looked at everything related on the internet, and nothing seemed to work. This is the code where I insert the data in the database and where I display the date and time in text views.

```
databaseHelperAlarm = new DatabaseHelperAlarm(this);

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        final int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        final int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        final int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        final int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        final int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    xml_arrow_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AddAlarmActivity.this, AlarmActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    xml_fab_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String title = xml_title.getText().toString();
            String date = xml_date.getText().toString();
            String time = xml_time.getText().toString();
            String repeat = xml_repeat.getText().toString();

            if ((xml_title.getText().toString().equals("")) || (xml_date.getText().toString().equals("")) || (xml_time.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fields Must Not Be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                databaseHelperAlarm.insertData(title, date, time, repeat);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reminder Made", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddAlarmActivity.this, AlarmActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

   xml_set_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(xml_set_date.getWindowToken(), 0);
            xml_title.clearFocus();

            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(AddAlarmActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy");
                            String dateString = format.format(calendar.getTime());
                            xml_date.setText(dateString);
                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
            if(!datePickerDialog.isShowing()){
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        }
    });

    xml_set_time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(xml_set_time.getWindowToken(), 0);
            xml_title.clearFocus();

            timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(AddAlarmActivity.this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

                            String chosenHour = "";
                            String chosenMinute = "";
                            String chosenTimeZone = "";
                            if(selectedHour > 12){
                                chosenTimeZone = "PM";
                                selectedHour = selectedHour - 12;
                                if(selectedHour < 10){
                                    chosenHour = "0"+selectedHour;
                                }else{
                                    chosenHour = ""+selectedHour;
                                }
                            }else{
                                chosenTimeZone = "AM";
                                if(selectedHour < 10){
                                    chosenHour = "0"+selectedHour;
                                }else{
                                    chosenHour = ""+selectedHour;
                                }
                            }

                            if(selectedMinute < 10){
                                chosenMinute = "0"+selectedMinute;
                            }else{
                                chosenMinute= ""+selectedMinute;
                            }

                            xml_time.setText(chosenHour + ":" + chosenMinute +" "+chosenTimeZone);
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });}
```

}

My guess is that I need to make another Curser or something, but I have no idea where to start. Here is part of the code from my database though.

```
public void  insertData (String a_title, String a_date, String a_time, String a_repeat){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(A_TITLE, a_title);
        contentValues.put(A_DATE, a_date);
        contentValues.put(A_TIME, a_time);
        contentValues.put(A_REPEAT, a_repeat);

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        sqLiteDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        sqLiteDB.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<AlarmInfo> getMainInfo() {
        ArrayList<AlarmInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                AlarmInfo ai = new AlarmInfo();
                ai.setiD(cursor.getInt(0) + "");
                ai.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                ai.setDate(cursor.getString(2));
                ai.setTime(cursor.getString(3));
                list.add(ai);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return list;
    }

    public Cursor getAllData(int getId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +
                A_ID + "=?", new String[] {Integer.toString(getId)});
        return res;
    }
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you have two relatively easy ways, perhaps used together.

You could a) **delete** rows when the alarm time has expired. It may be that the **repeat column** is used to repeat the alarm in which case an **update** rather than a delete would be required (this would require b)).

You could b) also be more specific in regard to the query/queries that drive the addition of the alarm to **only select rows for future date/times**.

So no real need for another cursor as such.

---

Personally I would (and have used, as below) use a single column for date and time using a **timestamp**, rather than trying to work with two columns.

The following is an example, akin to selection based upon date/time. (handling repeating rules that add items to a shopping list on a regular user defined basis) :-

```
String filter = DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_ACTON_COL +
    " <= " +
    Long.toString(getDateTimeOfAllofToday()) +
    SQLAND +
    DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_PROMPT_COL +
    " = 0 ";
```

(`DBRulesTableConstants.RULES_????_ COL` equates to column names, `SQLAND` is `AND`), `getDateTimeofALlofToday`, returns the timestamp 1 millisecond before midnight of the current day (i.e. in this case I want all rules before and on today (bar that 1 millisecond :))).

e.g. running this now ( about 14:20 20th Sept 2017) results in the filter being :-

```
ruleacton <= 1505915999999 AND ruleprompt = 0
```

This being incorporated into the query's `WHERE` clause e.g. :-

```
SELECT ........ WHERE ruleacton <= 1505915999999 AND ruleprompt = 0  ;
```

Just in case you're interested here's `getDateTimeOfAllofToday` :-

```
private long getDateTimeOfAllofToday() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1); // tomorrow
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND,-1);
}
```